# Getting several plots from different data frames on one page with an individual intercept in R using (ggplot2 xintercept marrangeGrob geom_vline)

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2, gridextra

I am a R beginner and I tried to search the forum for possible answers, however I haven't found my questions. Apologize if I missed some obvious description somewhere.

I want to plot several density-plots on one page with individual vertical intercepts, which are derived from different data frames.Thus I would read in my data, produce a loop to calculate the 99.quantile to later set this as the vertical intercepts.

```
library(reshape)
require (ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
```

example data generation

```
N=1000
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }

cat1 <- sample("comp1", N, replace=T)
cat2 <- sample("comp2", N, replace=T)
cat3 <- sample("comp3", N, replace=T)
comp1 <- data.frame(cat1, values=(rnorm2(1000,5,1)))
comp2 <- data.frame(cat2, values=(rnorm2(1000,10,1)))
comp3 <- data.frame(cat3, values=(rnorm2(1000,7,1)))



> head(comp1)
   cat1   values
1 comp1 4.411908
2 comp1 5.841363
3 comp1 6.358820
4 comp1 4.080915
5 comp1 7.232419
6 comp1 5.737979
>
```

And my loop

```
graphs = list()
i = 1
comparisons <- list(comp1= comp1,comp2=comp2,comp3=comp3)
names_list <- names(comparisons)


for(df in comparisons) {
    threshWin99 <- as.numeric(quantile(df$values,probs = .99))
    title <-  names_list[i]  
    graphs[[i]]<- ggplot(data=df, aes(x= values)) +
      geom_density(data=df)+ 
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.numeric(threshWin99)),linetype="dashed")+
      labs(title=title)
    }
  ml = do.call(marrangeGrob, list(grobs=graphs, nrow = 4, ncol = 2))
  ggsave(paste0("XYZ.pdf"), plot = ml , width = 210, height = 297, units = "mm")
```

This works fine until I am using the last command with do.call and marrangeGrob.
It only saves and uses the last "threshWin99" in his memory and does not plot the intercept individually. I am getting different plots with different title but the same intercept.

[plot from loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM0g0.png)

If I check within the loop before using this command, the "intercept-list" is correct!  Same is true for graphs...

```
 a[[i]]<- value
     > a
```

[single plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFyMx.png)

I thus believe that something happens in the MarrangeGrob command, which I do not use correct. Can anybody help me?
I also tried with grid.arrange

```
b <- do.call(grid.arrange, c(graphs,  nrow = 4,ncol=2))
```

Add-on - this also doesn't help: the R-cookbook entry Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)

```
source("multiplot.R")
multiplot(graphs[[1]],graphs[[2]],graphs[[3]])
```

I get the same "error" that I plot the same intercept on all sub-graphs. 
Somehow the geomvline aes makes a conflict? Or the intercept is overwritten??

Thanks a lot! ;D Hopefully I did not forget to mention anything...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself with the help of nice colleagues and I want to share the answer:

I had to change my ggplot command and removed the "aes" in the geom_vline part, as this made the conflict.

```
graphs[[i]]<- ggplot(data=df) +
                    geom_density(aes(x=values))+ 
                    geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(quantile_test),linetype="dashed")+
                    labs(title=paste0("",title," ",quantile_test))
```